# Citation in complied document not in the order of .bib file using \bibliographystyle{unsrt}. Using Miktex and texstudio (Bibtex)

Tags: cross-referencing

My problem is that the first ref on text appears as [5] and changes as I add more chapters to different numbers instead of [1]. I've seen many similar problems and tried suggested solutions but my problem still persists. I would like the bibliography to follow the order of my text file. i.e., the first ref entry on my text is number [1], and so on. It seems like the references are following an alphabetical order even though my bibliography style is `unsrt`.

I've tried many ways to resolve my problems still no luck. I recently tried inserting `\nocite{*}` in the document just before the bibliography command and it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated. I am writing a thesis and this is the main part below:

```
\documentclass[openany, a4paper,12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{epsfig,amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp,   % for \textlangle and \textrangle macros
    xspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{tabularx} % Allows table to fit in page
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
    modules = all,
    formula = mhchem
}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black}
\usepackage{natbib}
\pagestyle {plain}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Defining prime for latexpdf%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand*{\myprime}{^{\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand*{\mydprime}{^{\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
\newcommand*{\mytrprime}{^{\prime\prime\prime}\mkern-1.2mu}
%%%%%loading the shapes.geometric and arrows library from the tikz package%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows} 
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{cite}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\abbrlabel}[1]{\makebox[5cm][l]{\textbf{#1}\ }}%\dotfill
\newenvironment{abbreviations}{\begin{list}{}{\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\abbrlabel}}}{\end{list}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%controlling chapter and sections andsubsections%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    
\phantomsection
\input{title.tex}
\phantomsection
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{abstract.tex}
\input{preface.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
\phantomsection
\input{Declaration.tex}
\input{publications.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Declaration}
\phantomsection
\input{dedication.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Dedication}
\phantomsection
\input{acknowledge.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgments}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents
\phantomsection
\normalsize{\listoffigures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of figures}
\phantomsection
\normalsize{\listoftables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of tables}
 
 \phantomsection
 \input{Abbreviations.tex}
 
\phantomsection
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\input{chapter1.tex}
\input{chapter22.tex}
\input{chapter3.tex}
\input{chapter4.tex}
\input{chapter5.tex}
\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}   
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: afaik, `unsrt` means sorting in order of appearance in the text, not in a bib file. This is in contrast to sorting in alphabetical order or publication year or other criteria. I don't think there is an easy to have an arbitrary sorting such as bib file appearance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have made some edits to my question.  Yes, I would like my bibliography to follow the order of text referencing. I tried using the command `unsrt` but still, the first text reference appears as [5] instead of [1]. Is there another way I could force it such that the first ref on my text document is [1] and the second is [2] and so on? Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: it would help if you could provide a minimum working example (MWE), that is the minimum document that reproduces your problem. here we cannot take the source you provide and compile it to reproduce your issue and try and fix it.